# Como posso moldar o objeto gerado pelo FromBuilder?

Tags: angular, angular-6

Eu uso o FormBuilder pra gerar um objeto e enviar para uma API, mas o objeto gerado não é bem o formato que a API espera. Eu preciso saber como adiciono objetos dentro de objetos usando o FormBuild. Eu fiz uma "gambiarra" pra poder funcionar, mas queria saber como fazer de maneira mais profissional.

```
createForm(create) {
this.formRegister = this.formBuilder.group({
  nome: [create.nome, [ Validators.required ]],
  email: [create.email, [ Validators.required, Validators.email ]],
  celular: [create.celular, [ Validators.required ]],
  cpf: [create.cpf, [ Validators.required ]],
  senha: [create.senha, [ Validators.required ]],
  sexo: [create.sexo, [ Validators.required ]],
  dataNascimento: [create.dataNascimento, [ Validators.required ]]
});
```

}

Estava usando essa função pra moldar meu objeto

```
objTransf() {
let data = new PreCadastro;
data = {
  'pessoa': {
    'nome': this.formRegister.value.nome,
    'email': this.formRegister.value.email,
    'cpf': this.formRegister.value.cpf,
    'sexo': this.formRegister.value.sexo,
    'dataNascimento': this.formRegister.value.dataNascimento,
    'contato': {
      'celular': this.formRegister.value.celular
    }
  },
  'usuario': {
    'login': this.formRegister.value.email,
    'senha': this.formRegister.value.senha
  },
  'preCadastro': true
  };
  this.addElement(data);
  }
```

Se tiverem um link de uma matéria ou exemplo, seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O melhor seria pra cada objeto encadeado que vc tem. Vc criar outro formGroup dentro do seu formGroup assim ele fica com a estrutura do jeito que vc precisa.

```
this.formRegister = this.formBuilder.group({
  pessoa: this.formBuilder.group({
      nome: [create.nome, [ Validators.required ]],
      email: [create.email, [ Validators.required, Validators.email ]],
      celular: [create.celular, [ Validators.required ]],
      cpf: [create.cpf, [ Validators.required ]],
      senha: [create.senha, [ Validators.required ]],
      sexo: [create.sexo, [ Validators.required ]],
 })
 usuario: this.formBuilder.group({
      senha: [create.senha, [ Validators.required ]],
      login: [create.email, [ Validators.required, Validators.email ]]
 })
});
```

ai use no html assim:

```
<div formGroupName="pessoa">
```